# seaborn remove duplicate legend when applying style and size to same variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization, legend

How can I fix up the legend of seaborn?
When plotting: `hue = 'group', style='bar', size='bar'` is used for the various categories in 2 dimensions.
I want to apply bar to size and style for a better distinction. However 1) the different sizes do not reflect well in legend 2) they are a duplication of the information available in the legend from the style property.

I want to remove this duplication and only have the values of `bar` once in the legend, but with each respective style, but in the corresponding size

```
%pylab inline

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

df = pd.DataFrame({'dt':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-03'], 'group':['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'bar':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2], 'baz':[3,4,2, 6, 10,8,9, 20]})
display(df)
sns.lineplot(x='dt', y='baz', data=df, hue = 'group', style='bar', size='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.06-customizing-legends.html - legend size of points seems interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a simple answer to the question:
passing `legend = 'full'` yields the desired result.